# Prevent React from warning about unrecognized properties on mock objects

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking

Is there a way make React ignore mock-specific properties of mock objects at unit test time to avoid seeing a plethora of warnings in the console?

Some of our unit tests are mocking objects, which is causing React to warn about unrecognized props. Examples:

> Warning: React does not recognize the `_isMockFunction` prop on a DOM element.
>
> Warning: React does not recognize the `getMockImplementation` prop on a DOM element.
>
> Warning: React does not recognize the `mockClear` prop on a DOM element.

... and so on and so forth.

We are using the `mock` method of the npm package 'jest-mock-extended', as well as normal `jest.fn()` mocks.

I've looked into these warnings and it doesn't seem like the usual solution of "don't attach those properties" won't work, here. It seems harmful to change the production code just to make tests work better, and I think the objects being passed in need to remain mocks.

If there's a better way to do this than mocking, I'm all ears.